# PHP Array Conversion to String for using in SQL Statement

Tags: php, arrays

How can i change an array `[["English","French","Spanish","German"]]` in a String using for IN clause in Sql Statement.

e.g.s

```
 "SELECT a.ad_id FROM `category_rel` a INNER JOIN tbl_category_master b ON a.category_id= b.fld_category_id WHERE b.fld_category_name IN ('English', 'French', "Spanish', 'German')";
```

I have store this array in `$category= [["English","French","Spanish","German"]]`  variable and use in below SQL Statement.

```
 "SELECT a.ad_id FROM `category_rel` a INNER JOIN tbl_category_master b ON a.category_id= b.fld_category_id WHERE b.fld_category_name IN ('$category')"
```

Please Help me out. thank you.

this is my php code:

```
    <?php

  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
  $city = $_POST['city'];
  $category=json_encode(array($_POST['category']));

   echo $category;
  $cat= "'".implode("','", $category[0])."'";
    echo $cat;

 $con->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

     $sql="SELECT c.ad_id FROM `category_rel` c INNER JOIN tbl_category_master d ON c.category_id= d.fld_category_id WHERE d.fld_category_name IN ($cat)";
    $result1=$con->query($sql);

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
    $output[] = $row;
 }
   echo json_encode(array("result"=>$output));
  $ids[]=json_encode(array($output));


      $stmtsearch="SELECT a.title, a.phone, a.description, a.email, a.post_date FROM `ad_master` a INNER JOIN tbl_city_master b ON a.city_id = b.fld_city_id WHERE b.fld_city_name = '$city' AND a.id IN ('2','11','28') ORDER BY id" ;

  $resultsearch=$con->query($stmtsearch);
     $json=array();
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultsearch)){

   array_push($json, 
  array('title'=> $row[0],
      'phone'=> $row[1],
       'description'=> $row[2],
      'email'=>$row[3],
      'post_date'=>$row[4]
     ));
    }
   echo json_encode(array("result"=>$json));
  $con->close();
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$category` array into `IN` clause query by using `implode()` function as

```
 $category= [["English","French","Spanish","German"]];
 $cat= "'".implode("','", $category[0])."'";// return 'English','French','Spanish','German'
 $query="SELECT a.ad_id FROM `category_rel` a INNER JOIN tbl_category_master b ON a.category_id= b.fld_category_id WHERE b.fld_category_name IN ($cat)"; // pass your cat here
```

Comment: No sir,it doesn't work.. it show invalid argument passed in implode  @Saty

Comment: No its working my code output is `SELECT a.ad_id FROM category_rel a INNER JOIN tbl_category_master b ON a.category_id= b.fld_category_id WHERE b.fld_category_name IN ('English','French','Spanish','German')`

Comment: You have to miss something!! Post what you have done!!

Comment: Sir, I have edited my code. Please go through it. Thank you   @Saty

Comment: What `echo $category;` echo also post value of `print_r($_POST['category'])`

Comment: I applied echo to see the result .

Comment: Thank You Sir, It is working now..I removed all echo in my code. @saty

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
<?php

$category = [["English","French","Spanish","German"]];

$inCategory = '"' . implode('","', $category[0]) . '"';

$sql = "SELECT a.ad_id FROM `category_rel` a INNER JOIN tbl_category_master b ON a.category_id= b.fld_category_id WHERE b.fld_category_name IN ($inCategory)";

echo $sql;
```

Comment: No sir,it doesn't work.. it show invalid argument passed in implode   @Julie Pelletier

Comment: That's probably because the information your provided showing two layers of arrays is not right.  Try it without the `[0]` and tell me if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function with ',' delimiter.

```
$categoryCondition = implode(",", $category);
```